# how to get a Table object given its name (as String) in Jackcess

Tags: jackcess

im starting with java and jackcess, I have this code

```
public class DataManagement {
static Database db;
static Database dbopen;
static Table Users;
static Set<String> tablename;
static String[] nametabla;

public static void opendatabase(){
   try {
    dbopen=DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("D:/alex.accdb"));
    tablename=dbopen.getTableNames();
    nametabla = tablename.toArray(new String[0]);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void readtabla (String name){
   System.out.println(name);
   for(Column column : name.getColumns()) {
    String columnName = column.getName();
    System.out.println(columnName + " " );


  }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    /*opening an existing database*/
    opendatabase();
    System.out.println("the name of tables are " + tablename);
    System.out.println("the name of table 2 is " + nametabla[1]);
    readtabla(nametabla[1]);


}
}
```

without the "for" inside of the method readtabla  I get this

```
 the name of the tables are [Establecimiento, Estado, Medición, Ubicación]
 the name of table 2 is Estado
 Estado
```

the problem lies here

```
 for(Column column : name.getColumns())
```

because name must be (I think) a Table type and I send it as a string type, so how can I convert string type into Table type?
or there's another way ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getTable()` method of the Database object to return a Table object:

```java
public static void readtabla (String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
    Table tbl;
    try {
        tbl = dbopen.getTable(name);
        for(Column column : tbl.getColumns()) {
            String columnName = column.getName();
            System.out.println(columnName + " " );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr Thompson, it works now thank you very much, one last question, why the name of the first column appears last?

Comment: @user3155736 By default Jackcess will list the columns in DATA order, the order in which the columns were added to the table. You can use `dbopen.setColumnOrder(Table.ColumnOrder.DISPLAY);` to tell Jackcess to work with the columns in DISPLAY order.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jackcess-orm](https://github.com/amgohan/jackcess-orm) to manipulate only java POJOs